# Is there any known experimental violation of Einstein's $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, relativity, mass-energy

Note that I am not talking about $E_0= m_0c^2$ but $E=mc^2$, where m is the relativistic mass. I know that one holds for stationary particles, moving particles, even light, I read that it even holds true for increases in mass due to temperature and such. So my question is:

- Is there any form of energy that doesn't cause that exact increase in mass?
- Conversely is there any mass that doesn't hold $c^2/\mathrm{kg}$ [J] of energy?
- Is there any phenomena at all where this equation doesn't hold?

I am interested in experimental tests, not theoretical arguments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97428/discussion-on-question-by-user1316208-is-there-any-known-experimental-violation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *no* measurements in which violations of Special Relativity have been observed. There are *no* known “exceptions” to Special Relativity when it is properly applied. Any confirmed discovery of an exception would be worldwide news and an immediate candidate for the Nobel Prize. After 114 years, Einstein is *still* right (even without a Nobel for SR), and I predict that in another 114 years this will not have changed.

In my opinion he was also right about relativistic mass, a concept that he did not introduce and that he disliked.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97429/discussion-on-answer-by-g-smith-is-there-any-known-experimental-violation-of-ei).